# SQL concat rows with same ID and newest date

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012, rows, concatenation

I'm looking for help querying the output of my application's messages. I have a query which takes lines of each message and concats them together to form a sentence. However some of my message numbers have two or more messages, in this case I only want the message with newest date. My current code outputs all messages in a sentence by concatenating line numbers together in order for each message number and outputting them in order by MSG_NUM. I've added ordering by MSG_START_DATE but as expected that still gives me both. How can I do a select max for each concatenated message line?

Here are the fields I'm working with:

```
MSG_NUM | MSG_START_DATE  | MSG_LINE_NUM | MSG_TEXT

1       | 2010-01-15      | 1            | Invalid operation
1       | 2010-01-15      | 2            | try again
1       | 2014-02-21      | 1            | Invalid input
1       | 2014-02-21      | 2            | try again
```

Here is my current code:

```
Select distinct ST2.[MSG_NUM],
substring(
    (
        (Select ' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(ST1.[MSG_TEXT]))  AS [text()]
        From database..messages ST1 
        Where ST1.[MSG_NUM] = ST2.[MSG_NUM]
        ORDER BY ST1.[MSG_START_DATE], ST1.[MSG_LINE_NUM]
        For XML PATH (''),root('xmlchar'), type).value('/xmlchar[1]','varchar(max)')
    ), 2, 2000) [Message]
From database..messages ST2 order by ST2.[MSG_NUM]
```

And here is the output I receive:

> 1 Invalid operation try again Invalid input try again

I only want the output:

> 1 Invalid input try again

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: Added! (SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about you filtering by date ?

```
Select distinct ST2.[MSG_NUM],
substring(
    (
        (Select ' '+LTRIM(RTRIM(ST1.[MSG_LINE_NUM]))  AS [text()]
        From database..messages ST1 
        Where ST1.[MSG_NUM] = ST2.[MSG_NUM]
          AND ST1.[MSG_START_DATE] = (SELECT MAX(ST3.[MSG_START_DATE])
                                      FROM database..messages ST3
                                      WHERE ST2.[MSG_NUM] = ST3.[MSG_NUM]
                                     )
        ORDER BY ST1.[MSG_LINE_NUM]
        For XML PATH (''),root('xmlchar'), type).value('/xmlchar[1]','varchar(max)')
    ), 2, 2000) [Message]
From database..messages ST2 order by ST2.[MSG_NUM]
```

Better yet, just filter before passing to your query

```
WITH maxd
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,MAX(MSG_START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY [MSG_NUM]) AS maxdate
    FROM DATABASE..messages
    )
    ,filter
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM maxd
    WHERE MSG_START_DATE = maxdate
    )
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[MSG_NUM]
    ,substring((
            (
                SELECT ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ST1.[MSG_LINE_NUM])) AS [text()]
                FROM filter ST1
                WHERE ST1.[MSG_NUM] = ST2.[MSG_NUM]
                ORDER BY ST1.[MSG_LINE_NUM]
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,root('xmlchar')
                    ,type
                ).value('/xmlchar[1]', 'varchar(max)')
            ), 2, 2000) [Message]
FROM filter ST2
ORDER BY ST2.[MSG_NUM]
```

Comment: Wow! That did it! Thank you! I did make a minor mistake and the LTRIM(RTRIM(ST1.[MSG_LINE_NUM])) should actually be [MSG_TEXT] but thank you thank you! The rest worked!

Comment: Did you use first or second version?

Comment: I tried both, ended up going with the first. The second one spent more than two minutes executing before I cancelled it.